# recharts gives tooltip only for one vertical dot?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, recharts

I have series of lines like on the pic below. The problem is that it seems, that recharts won't give me the ability to select any dot, but one of the vertical.

[image]

My data for the first one line

```
0: {x: 1594900560000, y: 0.384}
1: {x: 1594900560000, y: 0.432}
```

The x is epoch time.

```
                <LineChart>
                 
                            <Line strokeWidth={3}
                                  dot={{fill: '#4D92F5', r: 5}} activeDot={{
                                onClick: () => {
                                    handleDotClick()
                                }
                            }} dataKey="y"
                                  data={data}/>
                        )
                    })
                    }
                    <CartesianGrid horizontal={false} stroke="rgba(16, 147, 200, 0.08)"/>
                    <XAxis
                        style={{
                            stroke: "rgba(16, 147, 200, 0.08)",
                            fill: 'rgba(12, 134, 184,1)'
                        }}
                        name="Time"
                        scale="time"
                        allowDuplicatedCategory={false}
                        type="number"
                        dataKey="x"/>
                    <YAxis
                        style={{
                            stroke: "rgba(16, 147, 200, 0.08)",
                            fill: 'rgba(12, 134, 184, 1)'
                        }}
                        type="number" dataKey="y"/>
                    <Tooltip
                        cursor={false}
                        labelFormatter={() => undefined}
                        formatter={(okay) => [new Intl.NumberFormat('en').format(okay), undefined]}/>
                </LineChart>
```